# Limit search results to only tweets in Google?

Tags: twitter, google-search

I am trying to search for a particular string and I want to see only results from all user's tweets.

"site:twitter.com" - doesn't work, because it searches in user's bio, name, etc., which I do not want.

p.s., I know that Twitter provides this results through its search, but I am interested in doing this through Google.

Answer (score 4):

All of a user's tweets are under the URL `https://twitter.com/username/status/` followed by a long series of digits. If you use `site:twitter.com/username/status` plus your keywords you should get what you want.

For instance, if you wanted to search all of Wil Wheaton's tweets where he mentions his cat Eliot...

```
site:twitter.com/wilw/status eliot
```

If you want to search *all* users' tweets, well, you would seem to be using the wrong tool for the job.

I tried `site:twitter.com/*/status keywords`, and seemed to get just tweets, but you may get different results depending on your keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `inurl:` search along with `site:`.

This search will return [all Hillary tweets from Trump](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:twitter.com%20AND%20inurl:%22realDonaldTrump%2Fstatus%22%20AND%20hillary).

```
site:twitter.com AND inurl:"realDonaldTrump/status" AND hillary
```

This search will return [all Hillary tweets from all others](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:twitter.com%20AND%20inurl:%22%2Fstatus%22%20AND%20hillary). Note: Google ranks Hillary's own tweets over all others.

```
site:twitter.com AND inurl:"/status" AND hillary
```

Comment: Google don't use the `AND`operator.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

The following could return all the indexed tweets:

[site:twitter.com inurl:/status/ -site:dev.twitter.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Atwitter.com+inurl%3A%2Fstatus%2F+-site%3Adev.twitter.com)

## Explanation

`site:twitter.com` will return all web pages from the twitter.com domain and its subdomains (each tweet has it's own web page)

`inurl:/status/` will return all web pages having /status/ on their URLs

`-site:dev.twitter.com` will return all web pages that are not from dev.twitter.com domain

Putting all together will rank high all the results that meet the three criteria. Other factors like your preferences, location and if you are signed in with a Google account could make that some results be ranked higher than others even if they don't meet the three criteria.

I tested this both signed in and in incognito mode without signing in and didn't see results from the bio or other twitter pages but didn't take a deep look as I got a couple of times the ["Unusual traffic from your computer network"](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en) warning.